# Jquery function not executing inside of a 'tap' function event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

Here is the function I have written

```
$('#move').bind('tap', function () {
    $('.page').addClass('slideLeftOut', function () {
    $('#wrapper').css("height","300");
    }); 
});
```

My problem is, I need the #wrapper's height to change to 300 AFTER the addClass..

I thought that this was the correct syntax for this, but it does not change the height after the addClass function.

Any Advice?

EDIT:

Here is a JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/A8T9f/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal jQuery `addClass` method does not take a callback function. It does not return until the operation is complete, so you can safely put the code on the following line:

```
$('#move').bind('tap', function () {
    $('.page').addClass('slideLeftOut');
    $('#wrapper').css("height","300");
});
```

---

Since you are using jQuery UI, however, this is a little trickier.  [The jQuery UI extension to `addClass`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/addClass/) does not provide a callback argument.

Since the UI `addClass` method uses [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate) internally, you could use the jQuery 1.6 `$.Deferred` enhancement, which allows you to call functions when all animations on an element are complete. This is easy to implement with `promise`:

```
$('#move').bind('tap', function () {
    $('.page').addClass('slideLeftOut').promise().done(function() {;
        $('#wrapper').css("height","300");
    });
});
```

See:

- [`$.Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object)
- [`$.fn.promise`](http://api.jquery.com/promise)
- [`deferred.done`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Note that this will only run when *all* animations are complete, not just the `addClass` one.

---

If you are using a browser's native animation capacity, I don't believe there is any easy way of finding out when an animation is finished. You'll need to do use `setTimeout` to run the code after a specified period of time.

[See jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8T9f/1/):

```
$('.page').addClass('slideLeftOut');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#wrapper').css("height","300");
}, 500);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix the issue :/. I will upload to jsFiddle

Comment: I have added the JSfiddle above, I made the #wrapper background red so you can see it. It should be successful if the red background is visible during the slideLeftOut animation and not after it is complete

Comment: The reason I am using webkit animations and not jquery is because the iOS uses hardware accelerations for webkit animations. It runs very smooth

Comment: @TaylorMac The native animations are the problem. See my edit.

Comment: very cool use of the setTimeout function. That is perfect, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you do this?

```
$('#move').bind('tap', function () {
    $('.page').addClass(function () {
    $('.page').addClass('slideLeftOut');
    $('#wrapper').css("height","300");
    }); 
});
```

I can't see a method with this signature: `addClass('slideLeftOut', function () {`

For more info, take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: :/ it is still adding the Class 'slideLeftOut' and changing the height of the #wrapper at the same time